# SQL Server Size of database including data associated with views

Tags: sql-server, view

I have a database with a couple tables and about 30 views in which the data comes from a few different databases.  Is there a way I can find out the total amount of data these tables PLUS views can access?  I am guessing it is around 200 GB but I would like a better way.

I have found plenty of ways to generate the total size of a database but I can't find something that will go out and get the amount of data a view has access to within a database as well.

The view is the tricky part.  Ideally it would get only the data size the view has access to but I suppose going to the table level would be acceptable.

Comment: "the amount of data a view has access to within a database"?  Would you count `CREATE VIEW MyView AS SELECT col1 FROM HugeTable WHERE col2 IS NULL` as having access to lots of data?  What if col2 is defined as `NOT NULL`?

Comment: @Anon.  Ideally no.  it would only count the data size that is the result of the query.  However, if that is not possible easily referencing the size of the table from the views in a database would help, as opposed to looking them all up indvidually.

Comment: Views don't have a size in the same way indexes and heaps do.  Do you want to know how much space you would need if you were to dump a `SELECT *` from all of your views, or do you want to know how much space the tables referenced by your views are using?

Comment: @Anon Thanks for the response.  Ideally I would like to know how much size a select * from my entire db which includes many views would be.  If that is not possible then somehow getting a list of the table sizes will have to be close enough.  Though I don't want to have to manually go through each table to look it up.

Answer (score 0):

if I understand correctly, you want to know the size of tables, if yes you can calculate the size of table by this query

```
EXEC sp_spaceused N'dbo.Customers';
```

Comment: I am actually looking to get the total size of the data accessible in a database, including views.  Since the view only references data in another table the size of a view is 0.  For instance if a view accessed 3 columns of a 10 column table I would like to know the amount of data that view had access to.  I can do this by looking at individual table sizes and estimating but that is inefficient and not too accurate.

Comment: What do you mean by "total size of the data accessible in a database, including views"? Would you consider `CREATE VIEW SummaryView AS SELECT SUM(col) FROM HugeTable` to be accessing lots of data?

Answer (score 0):

Attribution unknown:

```
SELECT
  CAST(OBJECT_NAME(stat.[object_id]) AS VARCHAR(50)) AS [Table Name],
  CAST(idxs.[name] AS VARCHAR(50)) AS [Index Name],
  stat.[row_count] AS [Number of Rows],
  cols.[width] AS [Row Width (bytes)],
  stat.[row_count] * cols.[width] AS [Space Used (bytes)],
  stat.[row_count] * cols.[width] / POWER(2,30) AS [Space Used (GB)]
FROM sys.dm_db_partition_stats AS stat
INNER JOIN sys.indexes idxs ON (idxs.[object_id] = stat.[object_id] AND idxs.[index_id] = stat.[index_id])
CROSS APPLY (SELECT SUM([length]) AS [width] FROM sys.syscolumns WHERE [id] = stat.[object_id]) cols
ORDER BY [Space Used (bytes)] DESC
```

Comment: Running this provides the size of my tables in the database plus the system base tables --sysobjvalues
syscolpars
syscolpars
sysxmlfacet
sysxmlcomponent
sysxmlcomponent
sysqnames as a sample.  No tables associated with the views.